# Using a Jupyter imported library?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

**Here is the big question:**

Do i need to explicitly install a library, such as Plotly, in order for my locally hosted Notebook to import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to have the library installed in your local environment to import it into your Jupyter Notebook.

However, you can check whether a package exists from within Jupyter Notebook and also automatically install it if it isn't already available.

you can run pip as well as shell commands from within a cell of the notebook

The syntax is as follows `!pip install plotly` Here the `!` explicitly forces the kernel to execute the command.

If it's already installed you'll get this message `Requirement already satisfied: plotly in /opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: What is an example where you'd want to install via pip from within a notebook cell??

Comment: And, is there a documented list of libraries that Anaconda supports out-of-box?